# referencing objects and properties within a class with multiple objects

Tags: javascript

Okay let's say I have the following:

```js
class Something {
  foo = {
    a: '123',
    get_a() {
      return this.a;
    }
  };

  bar = {
    b: '456',

    get_b() {
      return this.b;
    },

    get_c() {
      return this.get_a();

    }
  };

}
window.s = new Something();
window.s.bar.get_c();
```

If I were to use `s.bar.get_b()` it will return '456'. Within `get_b()` I can reference `this.b` and it looks to be a reference to `bar`.  However, when I attempt to call `s.bar.get_c()`, I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.get_a is not a function

Well based on my understanding of `this` being a reference to `bar`, I guess that makes sense. However, I don't understand what I need to do to actually reference `foo.get_a()` from `bar.get_c()`.  I've tried various things but nothing seems to work, short of just using `s.foo.get_a()` but I don't want to have to directly reference the `s` object. What am I missing here? I'm starting to suspect I'm fundamentally structuring my class wrong...

**Edit:** Not sure why someone felt the need to update my post to have it execute the code snippet.. seems overkill ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Anyways.. one thing I should have mentioned: in practice I'm not actually calling `s.foo.get_a()` from some other context outside of my class functions, which is why I mentioned not wanting to directly reference the `s` object. I was just putting the full path for sake of clarity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `arrow functions`:

```js
class Something {
  foo = {
    a: '123',
    get_a() {
      return this.a;
    }
  };

  bar = {
    b: '456',

    get_b() {
      return this.b;
    },

    get_c: () => {
      return this.foo.get_a();
    }
  };

}

const a = new Something();

console.log(a.bar.get_c());
```

Comment: I believe this is what I am looking for, yes! Now I just need to research how arrow syntax / functions actually work! Thanks!

Comment: @slinkhi Basically, `arrow functions` doesn't have `this`. So, when you call it inside it, js will start search for it like normal variables, following parent scope structure. In this case, it will find `this` in `Something` class. From there, you can access `foo` object. `Arrow functions` helps object oriented designs once it doesn't mess with `this` variables like normal functions, which has a different `this` from different scenarios.